# drop values in group by based on group criteria pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of data produced by the following:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['City','Address','date_time'])['house_price'].mean().pct_change()

City              Address                                      Date          Pct Ch
Washington, D.C.  111 S Street Appletown                       2018-08-03    0.298077
                                                               2018-08-11    0.000000
                                                               2018-08-17    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-07    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-17    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-20    0.000000
                  222 S Street Appletown                       2018-08-07    0.125926
                                                               2018-08-11    0.000000
                                                               2018-08-17    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-07    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-17    0.000000
                                                               2018-09-20    0.000000
```

I would like to remove the minimum dates in each group (2018-08-03 for 111 S Street Appletown; 2018-08-07 for 222 S Street).

I have tried

```
df2 = df.groupby(['City','Address','date_time'])['house_price'].mean().pct_change().filter(lambda x: x['date_time']> x['date_time'].min())
```

But this throws an error. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try (assuming the date is sorted )

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:,:])
```

Comment: df3 = df2.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:,:]) produces IndexingError: Too many indexers, while df.groupby(['City','Address','date_time'])['house_price'].mean().pct_change().apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:,:]) produces'float' object has no attirubte 'iloc'

Comment: @user2723494 after you get the df2 using this method

Comment: df2 = df.groupby(['City','Address','date_time'])['house_price'].mean().pct_change()
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2).groupby(level=[0,1,2]).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:,:]) produces ValueError: Duplicated level name: "City", assigned to level 3, is already used for level 0.

Comment: @user2723494 `df2.reset_index().groupby(df2.index.names[:-1]).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[1:,:])`